# Export object from typescript through webpack and use it in JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

What I'm trying to do is to bundle a library that I've wrote in Typescript with Webpack 2 and to be able to use this library even with vanilla JS. The building goes fine and without errors, but when it comes to use the exported object it appears like an empty object `{}`.

So what I've tried to do is the following:

- Bundle the library in a bundle.js file
- Create a my-js-script.js file that logs to the console the object exported by the .ts file
- Create a index.html file
- Import both the `bundle.js` and `my-js-script.js` files
- Serve the index.html file and see the object in the console.

#### Typescript file

```
import {SomeStuff} from 'some-stuff';

export class ClassA {
    constructor(){
        // Does other stuff with SomeStuff
    }
}

// What I want to achieve is something like this
export const myModule = new ClassA();
```

I thought that creating an html file that imports the bundle and my-js-script file were enough in order to have access to the `myModule` constant. But unfortunately it wasn't enough.

#### index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="./my-js-script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### Javascript file

```
myModule.doSomething();
```

What am I missing? Or there's simply non chances to do that? The webpack configuration is dead simple

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/web-onion.ts",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that this way. `myModule` won't be exported as a global. If you want to export something globally, use in the TypeScript file:

```
window.something = myModule
```

Note: you will have to either extend Window interface or use `(window as any)`.

Comment: I've tried your solution, it works partially. I can successfully log the object in console, but all the properties and methods are encapsulated inside the 
 __prototype__. Any chances to have them accessible via: myModule.met() instead of myModule.__proto__.constructor.met()?

Comment: This is how objects are supposed to work in JavaScript. Did you mean to access ClassA?

Comment: Did you mean that you are not able to do myModule.anyMethod()? Because that is not a normal behaviour.

Comment: Have you tried just to call `myModule.met();`? It should work.

Comment: Oh, it works! Thank you! It was just not showing any completition. Of course, because he knows nothing about that module... Anything I could do about that?

Comment: Use TypeScript instead of JavaScript.